# NodeJS net.socket recieves only first message

Tags: javascript, node.js, world-of-warcraft

Got a strange issue, that i have no idea how to deal with.
Trying to make auth server for World of Warcraft client application.

And here is what happening:

```
    const net = require('net')

const server = net.createServer((socket) => { 
    console.log('Client connected');    
    socket.removeAllListeners('data');
    socket.on('end', () => console.log('Client disconnected!'));    
    socket.on('close', () => console.log('Client closed connection to server.'));    
    socket.on('drain', () => console.log('Buffer drain!'));

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        onData(socket, data)
    });       
    socket.pipe(socket);
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Server error:' + err)
  });

function onData(socket, data) {
    console.log(`data length`, data.length)

    if (data.length === 44) {
        socket.write(Buffer.from('0000007cdc3e6e9cabc0cb57332ee5086df1b1ccc491d685996af531b4ec807ed2c667010720b79b3e2a87823cab8f5ebfbf8eb10108535006298b5badbd5b53e1895e644b891f97f4daa96fca449ea98bd3c8da6963012888a89b8e572abff4294e05c4fc98baa31e99a00b2157fc373fb369cdd2f100', 'hex'),
        (err) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            console.log(`Write data end`);
            socket.end(); //<-- also tried without FIN, since response packet is 0x0 terminated
        })        
    }
    console.log('onData::End');
}

server.listen(3724, '127.0.0.1', function() { 
    console.log('Server is listening');
});
```

Output from this is:

```
Server is listening
Client connected
<Buffer 00 08 28 00 57 6f 57 00 03 03 05 34 30 36 38 78 00 6e 69 57 00 55 52 75 72 b4 00 00 00 7f 00 00 01 0a 53 49 4c 56 45 52 4c 45 58 58>
data length 44
onData::End
Write data end
```

Thing is that in Wireshark i see next package from client, but JS code doesn't receive it and seems like stuck on first packet.
[image: Wireshark screen]

On image you can see first request with protocol WoW coming from client with 84 bytes lenght, then my response with 159 bytes, then one more client request with 115 bytes witch i'm not getting. (And according to Wireshark, structure of packet is good, since it's parsed)

Just to test things out i created small golang app with that same behavior.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net"
   "io"
   "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
   listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3724") 
   for {
      conn, err := listener.Accept() 
      if err != nil {
         continue
      }
      fmt.Println("New socket")
      go handleClient(conn) 
   }
}

func handleClient(conn net.Conn) {
   defer conn.Close() 

   buf := make([]byte, 0, 4096)
   tmp := make([]byte, 32)     
   for {      
       fmt.Println("Start read")
       n, err := conn.Read(tmp)
       fmt.Println("Stop read")
       if err != nil {
           if err != io.EOF {
               fmt.Println("read error:", err)
           }

           fmt.Println("EOF")
           break
       }
       buf = append(buf, tmp[:n]...)
       fmt.Println("total size:", len(buf))

       s := "0000007cdc3e6e9cabc0cb57332ee5086df1b1ccc491d685996af531b4ec807ed2c667010720b79b3e2a87823cab8f5ebfbf8eb10108535006298b5badbd5b53e1895e644b891f97f4daa96fca449ea98bd3c8da6963012888a89b8e572abff4294e05c4fc98baa31e99a00b2157fc373fb369cdd2f100"
       if len(buf) == 44 {
          data, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
          if err != nil {
              panic(err)
          }

          conn.Write(data)
       }
   }
   fmt.Println("total size:", len(buf))
}
```

And it works as supposed to, here is output:

```
New socket
Start read
Stop read
total size: 32
Start read
Stop read
total size: 44 //<-- first packet end, after this point we send response to client
Start read
Stop read
total size: 76 //<-- start reading second packet (so we got the next one)
Start read
Stop read
total size: 108
Start read
Stop read
total size: 119
Start read
```

So my question is where i messed up in NodeJS, it should be simple with almost no code, but i just have no idea.

**EDIT:** Just in case if it would help:

1. First client packet: 45000054aaed4000800600007f0000017f000001e5920e8c52e913174311bd4b501820fa346e000000082800576f57000303053430363878006e69570055527572b40000007f0000010a53494c5645524c455858
2. Second client packet:
   45000073ab094000800600007f0000017f000001e5920e8c52e913434311bdc2501820fa5ece00000191280a5b88b457d77d8df421b06e3d5c77a26b61b35c7fad12cdad9b71959e45395db29a611163d1d446e4a9973bf4f714afb6b532d1b21bdf3347de5aa780d270c01b1a43f15d510000

**UPDATE**:
Did a small client on NodeJS sockets, that simulates client behavior and it seems like working fine with server provided.

```
Server is listening
Client connected
<Buffer 00 08 28 00 57 6f 57 00 03 03 05 34 30 36 38 78 00 6e 69 57 00 55 52 75 72 b4 00 00 00 7f 00 00 01 0a 53 49 4c 56 45 52 4c 45 58 58>
data length 44
onData::End
Write data end
<Buffer 00 00 00 7c dc 3e 6e 9c ab c0 cb 57 33 2e e5 08 6d f1 b1 cc c4 91 d6 85 99 6a f5 31 b4 ec 80 7e d2 c6 67 01 07 20 b7 9b 3e 2a 87 82 3c ab 8f 5e bf bf ... 69 more bytes>
data length 119
onData::End
```

So that might be something specific with WoW client and NodeJS socket implementation. Still have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Looks like you close the connection with `socket.end();` when `data.length === 44`, so the socket can’t receive more data. With this in mind, I think your first output makes sense. I’m guessing if your first message has a length different from 44, the socket should remain open and you should be able to send more events. Also, what’s the purpose of `socket.pipe(socket);`?

Comment: As i stated in code (with comment), i also tried without `socket.end();` witch is sending FIN to client (all responses to client are null terminated, so it's doesn't really matters at this point), and closes only writing to socket. With `socket.pipe(socket)` we redirect all the data from the readable stream (server) to the writable stream (client).

Comment: Question - why you `socket.pipe(socket)`?

Comment: As both @PavelSavva and @Seti have mentioned you should re-evaluate that `pipe`. At a read-through it makes no sense in terms of talking to an actual remote application negotiating this protocol, and the equivalent isn't present in the Go code you've put forward.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your server is invoking the close event after the connection with client terminates? (I haven't seen your client side code yet)

Because if the server invokes the close event then it will not be able to conenct / receive from any other clients. Some of the websocket events are reserved and their logs might not reflect here even if you've explicitly defined the event.

Perhaps what you can also try is removing the `socket.close()` line and check what happens.

Comment: Thing is i have no idea about client implementation as well :D it's a proprietary Blizzard game - World of warcraft. The only thing i can see is packets that are sent over network. In that case im not calling socket.close(), only socket.end() and as it's stated above i tried to do it without ending socket as well already. Strange thing that that same actions are working fine with GoLang, Python and C++, but not with NodeJS ... and since i wanted to learn a bit more networking with NodeJS that was my main goal with this project.

Comment: Ok, that complicates things a bit. 

Because if the client sends a close event then your server will most probably stop listening since you've added the close event. I hope that's not the case :)

Answer (score 0):

The pipe() function reads data from a readable stream as it becomes available and writes it to a destination writable stream.

The example in the documentation is an echo server, which is a server that sends what it receives. The socket object implements both the readable and writable stream interface, so it is therefore writing any data it receives back to the socket

but still I think the problem must be there,and change with an other function